# Does showing Prima a complete Pokédex do anything?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

In the Diamond Settlement of the Crimson Mirelands, there is a man named Prima who says he'd love to see the Galaxy Team Pokédex when it's done.

What happens if you talk to Prima after the Pokédex is complete? Does he say or do anything special?

[image: Talking to prima]

[image: Map location for Diamond Settlement]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, that's just a dialogue entry.  In the postgame he says something different (a mild spoiler for the postgame, so I'll leave it out).   Nothing at all to do with the Pokédex, and he doesn't give an option to show it or do anything.

Comment: "a mild spoiler for the postgame" -> This is what spoiler tags are for :)

Comment: Can you add what he says in a spoiler tag?